# git push removes all server auto-generated files

Tags: git, moodle, git-push

I have git cloned an application to my working directory, but this application auto generates directories and files on server, so whenever I push any changes in my working directory, it removes the generated files and resets the application to it's initial state, how can I prevent this ? or how can I stage or track the auto generated files ?

Comment: Do you push changes directly to your git repo in your working tree? Or do you push to a bare repo, and have a post-receive hook making the update?

Comment: no, I push directly to repo

Comment: Which files? Moodle generates files in a data folder but its very important that the data folder is outside of the www root for security reasons. eg: in your config.php file $CFG->wwwroot = '/var/www/moodlesite'; and $CFG->dataroot = '/var/sitedata/moodlesite';